# How to insert JavaScript in JasperReports's report

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports

How to add *JavaScript* lines in *JasperReports*'s report?

I have added a static text field and made mark up as HTML and inserted the text as `<script></script>`

But it doesn't display *JavaScript* when exported

```
<band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
    <staticText>
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="79" backcolor="#EEEEEE"/>
        <textElement markup="html"/>
        <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">window.alert('hello');</script>]]></text>
    </staticText>
</band>
```

Am I missing some more attributes to set? And I can't find a concrete document explaining how to embed *JavaScript* code in report. Please provide link to any documentation if available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the way you are adding javascript in the HTML markup will be rendered as script in exported HTML. However I know the alternate way. See the code snippet below:

```
StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporter();

exporter.setParameter(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STRING_BUFFER, sbuf);
.
.
.
exporter.exportReport();

sbuf.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('hello');</script>");

String content = sbuf.toString();
```

The parameter OUTPUT_STRING_BUFFER sends the exported output to the StringBuffer (**sbuf** in this case). You can then append your script to this exported HTML and finally print the **content** using JSP like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Disposition' content='inline'>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:white">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="middle" align="center">
                     <%=content%>
                </td>
    </body>
</html>
```